how to pull each and every resource using ml-gradle in MarkLogic?
I have to setup ml-gradle for MarkLogic project, but they don't have any configs as of now. It is completely manual?
So, what is the best way to pull all the resources using:
mlExportResources -PincludeTypes=databases,servers

Is there a way to pull everything like users, roles, servers, etc. - all?
gradle -PexportPath=C:/export mlExportResources -PincludeTypes=databases,servers -PEnvironment=local

